# Upload Excel File to phpmysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello guys I am going to upload my excel to sql but while i upload i get this error there is shot screen you see it thanks 
[image]

this is the index.php i do not know which area it has problem please help me and let me the problem thanks a lot
everything work well but only got that error and also while can not upload to sql as well.

```
          <?php
           $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "invoice4");
           $output = '';
            if(isset($_POST["import"]))
             {
             $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["excel"]["name"])); // 
            For getting Extension of selected file
             $allowed_extension = array("xls", "xlsx", "csv"); //allowed 
              extension
              if(in_array($extension, $allowed_extension)) //check selected 
              file extension is present in allowed extension array
                {
               $file = $_FILES["excel"]["tmp_name"]; // getting temporary 
               source of excel file

                include("PHPExcel/IOFactory.php"); // Add PHPExcel Library 
                in this code
                $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file); // create 
                object of PHPExcel library by using load() method and in 
                load method define path of selected file

                $output .= "<label class='text-success'>Data Added: </label> 
               <br /><table class='table table-bordered'>";
               foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
                {
                $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
                  for($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)
                   {
                   $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet- 
                  >getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue());
                  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet- 
                  >getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue());
                 if(!empty($name) || !empty($email)) // if none of the data 
                 are empty
                   {
                   $output .= "<tr>";
                   $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_excel(name,email) VALUES 
                   ('".$name."', '".$email."')";
        mysqli_query($connect, $query);
       $output .= '<td>'.$name.'</td>';
       $output .= '<td>'.$email.'</td>';
       $output .= '</tr>';
      }
    }
  } 
  $output .= '</table>';
  $target_dir = "uploads/"; //file upload folder
   $target_file = $target_dir .time().basename($_FILES["excel"]["name"]); // 
  target file to be uploaded

    //upload the file
       if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["excel"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
      $fileUploadMsg= "<label class='text-success'>The file has been 
      uploaded Successfully!</label><br>";
       } else {
        $fileUploadMsg= '<label class="text-danger">Sorry, there was an 
        error uploading your file!</label><br>';
           }

             }
           else
      {
            $output = '<label class="text-danger">Invalid File</label>'; 
        //if non excel file then
       }
         }
          ?>

          <html>
           <head>
         <title>Import Data to SQL</title>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
            scale=1.0">
            <script 
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">

     </script>
     <script 
  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">

    </script>
         <link 

href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      rel="stylesheet" />
     <style>
       body
         {
         margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background-color: #0cb313b3;
        }
         .box
          {
          width:700px;
          border:1px solid #ccc;
          background-color:#fff;
          border-radius:5px;
           margin-top:100px;
            }
            input[type="file"]{
            border:1px solid gray;
             }

              </style>
               </head>
                <body>
             <div class="container box">
             <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <div class="container-fluid">
             <h3 align="center" class="text-success" style="font- 
              weight:600;">Excel to Mysql Importer</h3><br />
             <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:20px">
               <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4"></div>  <!-- Blank 
                Div -->
                 <div class="col-md-4 ">
                 <img src="img/excel.png" height="150px" width="150px">
                     </div>
                   </div>
                       <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <label>Select Excel File*</label>
                            </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-lg-5">
                        <input type="file" name="excel" />
                          </div>
                       <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-lg-7">
                <input type="submit" name="import" class="btn btn-info" 
             value="Import" style="padding:2px 20px;"/>
      </div>
     </div>
 </div>
   </form>
      <br />
           <br />
            <?php
             echo $output;
           echo @$fileUploadMsg;
           echo "<hr/>
        <p style='float:left'>* Supported Formats: .xls | .xlsx | .csv</p>
        <p style='float:right'><a href='export.php'>Exporter &#8594;</a> 
        </p>";
         mysqli_close($connect);
         ?>
         </div>
      </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Don't get confused.. `Sql` are language to query and `mysql` are database.

Comment: thanks for reply can you tell me clearly i do not understand your mean

Comment: `Hello guys I am going to upload my excel to sql` sql are language not database. `Sql = Structured Query Language`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using old version of PHP? Try change this :

```
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["excel"]["name"]));
```

to this :

```
$excel_name = explode(".", $_FILES["excel"]["name"]);
$extension = end($excel_name);
```

Because the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) mentions that `end()` function only accept array variable (not a function) as argument.

Comment: thanks for reply Dear Hasta Dhana but it is still the same problem

Comment: Dear Hast Dhana I have this $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["excel"]["name"]));